# Как в Kotlin проверить число, целое оно или дробное?

Tags: kotlin

У меня есть некоторая функция, при подстановке в которую значений переменной на выходе может получиться как дробное число, так и целое. Мне необходимо написать условие: если число n целое, то вывести его значение, если же число n дробное, то вывести некоторый текст. Можно пожалуйста пример кода этой ситуации?

Comment: В чем сложности?

Comment: Не знаю, как написать условие для n

Comment: Ну известно же, чем отличается дробное число от целого. Вот именно это и нужно проверить.

Comment: А какой тип на выходе-то?

Comment: В этом то и суть,мне надо написать код который определит тип числа на выходе

Comment: "У меня есть некоторая функция" - значит у вас есть ее заголовок, в котором указан возвращаемый тип. Укажите в вопросе, что это за тип.

Comment: может что то вроде`if (Math.abs(n % 1) > 0)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Подаем на функцию два вещественных числа, на выходе получаем строку в которой или целое число в строковом представлении, или какой-нибудь другой текст:

```
fun myFun(x: Double, y: Double): String {
    if (Math.floor(x / y) == (x / y)) {
        return ((x / y).toInt().toString())
    } else {
        return ("Some text")
    }
}
```

Проверяем:

```
println (myFun(4.0, 2.0))
println (myFun(5.0, 2.0))
println (myFun(5.0, 2.5))
println (myFun(9.4, 3.0))
println (myFun(8.8, 2.2))
```

Результат:

```
2
Some text
2
Some text
4
```

Answer (score -1):

Думаю, должно вывести так

```
fun main() {
    while (true){
        try {
            var a = readLine()?.toInt()
            break
        }
        catch (e:RuntimeException){
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).